# Explanation of $\{A_i\bigcup B_j\}_{i,j\in I\times J}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

It is in my understanding that a family, $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of sets $A_i$ with $i$ taking on all possible values within $I$. Of course this is the less formal definition; the most formal one being that which defines $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ as a graph, but I understand that that definition is seldomly used in practical theory. However, I have none of the idea of what  $\{A_i\bigcup B_j\}_{i,j\in I\times J}$ or $\{A_i\bigcap B_j\}_{i,j\in I\times J}$ means. Does it use the same logic? So it's the collection of the sets $\{A_i \bigcup B_j\}$ with $i$ and $j$ taking on all possible values within $I$ and $J$? So there should be $i$ times $j$ terms? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes this is what your intuition told you! (and you can show that both definition are equivalent if you wish to see it as graph but really you should see it as sets of sets it is way clearer)

Comment: So does $\{A_i'\}_{i\in I}$ also make sense? Does it mean the collection of all sets that are the complement of $A_i$ with $i$ ranging over all values in $I$?

Comment: Just the same as $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a map that maps $I$ into some set such that $i\mapsto A_i$ for all $i\in I$: $\{A_i\cap B_j\}_{i,j\in I\times J}$ is a map of $I\times J$ into some set, such that pairs $(i,j)\in I\times J$ map to those intersections, i.e. $(i,j)\mapsto A_i\cap B_j$ for all $i\in I, j\in J$.

Comment: You mean $A^c_i$? If you have trouble with indices, just consider that $(u_i)_{i \in I} \in X^I$ is just the data of a function $u: I \to X$ with some set $X$ and you just change the notation $u_i := u(i)$. Of course this works for anything. For your question take the composition of the function $i \mapsto A_i$ and the function $\bullet^c$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost Because I think the OP already knows the answer so all they need is confidence that they are right. In other words, I believe the correct answer is a three-letter "Yes!". But - that would be flagged as a low quality answer.